# Session in Restful Web service

Tags: web-services, session, rest, restful-authentication

i am using a Restful webservice with jersey framework. I have written a post method for user authentication. My problem now is to get the session id. How do i access my session object in web service. Also i read many times that its not a good practice to check for sessions in webservices. Why is this.

Answer (score 0):

REST by itself has no provisions, limitations and requirements on Authentication/Authorization.

I suggest you look into using OAuth 1.0a or 2.0 with your services. There are open-source libraries (both client and server side) in every language and other developers will know how to use your services if needed.